# How do I add jquery to magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How can I add js or jquery to magento 2.3 ?

Comment: it is already in magento since 2.0. https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.0/lib/web/jquery

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add it, depending on what you're looking to achieve, this link should help you: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/jquery-widgets-about.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using requirejs if editing a template file like so, there's no need to additionally include it as it's part of Magento 2 already:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'accordion'], function ($) {
        $("#element").accordion();
    });
</script>
```

This link provides further explanation and uses: https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-use-jquery-and-requirejs-in-magento-2-javascript-solutions.html